# FATAL: could not open directory "pg_tblspc/pvkar3/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, vps

I have a question. Today I can’t connect to my Postgres server. Sorry, I can't post image.

```
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: 2022-11-05 15:27:00.582 UTC [1676373] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: 2022-11-05 15:27:00.585 UTC [1676373] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc/pvkar3/PG_12_201909212": Not a directory
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: 2022-11-05 15:27:00.588 UTC [1676372] LOG:  startup process (PID 1676373) exited with exit code 1
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: 2022-11-05 15:27:00.588 UTC [1676372] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: 2022-11-05 15:27:00.590 UTC [1676372] LOG:  database system is shut down
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps postgresql@12-main[1676357]: Examine the log output.
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Nov 05 15:27:00 testVps systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main.
```

When I log error, the result like image. I don’t know how to fix this. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It could be disk corruption.  Or maybe a filesystem mount point just came undone.  Inspect pg_tblspc/pvkar3/PG_12_201909212 and the path leading up to it to see what is going on with it.

Comment: Looks like you lost a tablespace.